# ResponseEntity<JSON> - no content-length in header

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm making simple http service with Spring Boot RestController, and what I was found, when I try to request via GET Json object I didn't get content-length in header and transfer-encoding becomes chunked.

With simple `ResponseEntit<String>` all headers set as expected.

What kind of problem may lead to this behavior?

Comment: ResponseEntity is meant to represent the entire HTTP response. You can control anything that goes into it: status code, headers, and body.

Comment: Hi, @Sonique, do you find out what the problem was. I am experiencing something similar now.

Answer (score 4):

Ths is not a problem, Transfer-encoding `chuncked` and no content length means that response was compressed. If compression is enabled in Spring boot it will compress responses larger than certain amount (2048 bytes by default). I think your `ResponseEntit<String>` is simply smaller than required for compression.

You can read more about compression settings in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression).

If you want consistency you can either disable compressing, or set `server.compression.min-response-size` to a very small value. But I would suggest to keep it as is.

Comment: Link is dead, here is the new one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-enable-http-response-compression